# Adding Bar Chart to a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to add a Bar Chart to a React Component and used [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXuElLhCK8s) for it. I use react-chartjs-2

My component looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

const Daily = () => {
 
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    datasets: [],
  })
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({
    datasets: [],
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    setChartData({
      labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'e',
          data: [2,6,3,8,4,6,77],

        }
      ]
    });
    setChartOptions({
      responsive: true,
      plugins : {
        legend: {
          position: "top",
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'eh'
        }
      }
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="Daily">
    <Bar data={chartData} options={chartOptions} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Daily;
```

Even though I followed the tutorial exactly I get a lot of errors in the console and no Chart shows up. The errors are:

- Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
- You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
- You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
- You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
  See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
- react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the
  <ForwardRef(ChartComponent)> component:

My React and React DOM versions are
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-chartjs-2": "^4.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0", so they do seem to be matching and I'm wondering why I'm getting the error. useRef is also not referenced anywhere.

Did anyone have a similiar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think chartOptions should be {} and not {datasets:[]}

```
const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({});
```

Comment: Youre, right, thank you! Unfortunately this didn't change anything regarding the errors I'm getting.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and it worked fine https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-architecture-98cpx9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you have installed chart.js also right??

Comment: Yes, both are installed!

Comment: everything here seems good to me maybe problem might be in other component if any